# Which k8s version is required for Ecplise hono 1.0.0?

Tags: kubernetes, eclipse-hono

Can Eclipse Hono 1.0.0 Archive or Eclipse Hono 1.0.1 Archive be deployed in K8s v1.13.0?

Answer (score 1):

No, the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/deployment/helm-based-deployment/#kubernetes-cluster) explicitly states that the first supported Kubernetes version is 1.13.6.

Comment: However, this doesn't mean that it cannot be deployed on earlier versions. It only means that we haven't tested it with earlier versions. FMPOV it should work on 1.13.0 as well. We would be interested in hearing whether it works or not.

Comment: Didn't work with 1.11.0 and 1.13.0. when upload eclipse-hono-1.0.0.tgz, the system message said "Parsing error....."

Comment: @BobOntario when do you see this message? During deployment? Or later? Did you follow the [deployment guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/deployment/helm-based-deployment/#deploying-hono)? I recommend opening a new question where you describe what exactly you tried and which error occurred.

Comment: Just let you know that we have deployed hono-1.0.0 on 1.13.10. But with some issues that I will post another new question to address them here.